# Linq MVC with view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel

I am very new to ASP.NET/MVC/LINQ. I have three table in my database and their corresponding models in my solution:

```
salesperson
  id
, name
, address
, dob

sales
  id
, shopid
, salespersonid
, productid
, AmountSale
, saleDate

Shop
  id
, shopName
, Location
```

I also have a stored procedure which will return following data for all sales person:

```
  SalesPersonid
, TotalAmount_Sale
, Most_Recent_ShopName
, Count_Of_sales_Lifetime
, count_of_sales_ThisMonth
```

How do I call the stored procedure using LINQ and display the data in the front end? All of the samples I've seen so far return a model which already exists. I am very confused please help.

Comment: Are you using any kind of ORM? (Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc.)

Comment: And do you need to use a stored procedure?

Comment: Typically you would not use stored procedures, you'd usually use the Entity Framework ORM. [Calling stored procedures with Entity Framework](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/calling-stored-procedures-from-entity-framework.aspx) is absolutely possible, but it is usually something you do rarely and only to optimize specific cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind adding a library into the mix:

First, go install [Dapper dot Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper). Then, establish a model to store your results in:

```
class MySprocResult
{
  public int SalesPersonid { get; set; }
  public decimal TotalAmount_Sale { get; set; }
  public string Most_Recent_ShopName { get; set; }
  public int Count_Of_sales_Lifetime { get; set; }
  public int count_of_sales_ThisMonth { get; set; }
}
```

Next, establish a database connection and use Dapper dot net to return the results:

```
String connectionString = "connectionString";
using (IDbConnection db = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Open SQL connection
    db.Open();

    // Fetch results from stored procedure
    IEnumerable<MySprocResult> results = db.Query<MySprocResult>(
        "mySprocName",                           // stored procedure name

        //--- OPTIONAL
        //param: new { id = 123 },               // pass parameters if necessary
        //--- /OPIONAL

        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure // tell dapper it's a SPROC
    );

    // Close SQL connection
    db.Close();

    /* work with "results" here */
}
```